# How to initialize a database connection only once and reuse it in run-time in python?

Tags: python, database, class

I am currently working on a huge project, which constantly executes queries. My problem is, that my old code always created a new database connection and cursor, which decreased the speed immensivly. So I thought it's time to make a new database class, which looks like this at the moment:

```
class Database(object):

   _instance = None

   def __new__(cls):
      if cls._instance is None:
         cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
         try:
            connection = Database._instance.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="", database="db_test")
            cursor = Database._instance.cursor = connection.cursor()
         except Exception as error:
            print("Error: Connection not established {}".format(error))
         else:
            print("Connection established")
      return cls._instance
    
   def __init__(self):
      self.connection = self._instance.connection
      self.cursor = self._instance.cursor
   
   # Do database stuff here
```

The queries will use the class like so:

```
def foo():
   with Database() as cursor:
      cursor.execute("STATEMENT")
```

I am not absolutly sure, if this creates the connection only once regardless of how often the class is created. Maybe someone knows how to initialize a connection only once and how to make use of it in the class afterwards or maybe knows if my solution is correct. I am thankful for any help!

Comment: You don't really need `__new__` for this.  Just use `Database.connection` instead of `self.connection` inside `__init__` and your other methods.

Comment: @TimRoberts But how could I use `Database.connection`, if my class does not contain a connection, since the `__new__` method creates it? Maybe I am missing something out, would be nice if you could explain it to me! Thank you already!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Explanation

The keyword here is clearly **class variables**. Taking a look in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), we can see that class variables, other than instance variables, are shared by all class instances regardless of how many class instances exists.

> Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class:

So let us asume you have **multiple** instances of the class. The class itself is defined like below.

```
class Dog:
   
   kind = "canine"          # class variable shared by all instances

   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name      # instance variable unique to each instance
```

In order to better understand the differences between class variables and instance variables, I would like to include a small example here:

```
>>> d = Dog("Fido")
>>> e = Dog("Buddy")
>>> d.kind   # shared by all dogs
"canine"
>>> e.kind   # shared by all dogs
"canine"
>>> d.name   # unique to d
"Fido"
>>> e.name   # unique to e
"Buddy"
```

## Solution

Now that we know that class variables are shared by all instances of the class, we can simply define the connection and cursor like shown below.

```
class Database(object):

   connection = None

   def __init__(self):
      if Database.connection is None:
         try:
            Database.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="", database="db_test")
         except Exception as error:
            print("Error: Connection not established {}".format(error))
         else:
            print("Connection established")

   def execute_query(self, sql):
      cursor = Database.connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
```

As a result, the connection to the database is created once at the beginning and can then be used by every further instance.
Note that the cursor is not cached, since it takes essentially no time at all to create a cursor. However, creating a connection is quite expensive, so it is sensible to cache them.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of like this.  It's a cheap way of using a global.

```
class Database(object):
   connection = None

   def __init__(self):
      if not Database.connection:
         Database.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="", database="db_test")

   def query(self,sql):
      cursor = Database.connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
   
   # Do database stuff here
```

Comment: You mean it's the cheap way, so I asume there is still a better way to solve my problem? Does this solution also works with the class usage within the quieres like shown in my question? Huge thanks to you, you already helped me a lot!

Comment: When I do this, I usually store the database connection in a global, but storing it in a class member like this provides better encapsulation.

Comment: Good to know, but since I only work with the class anyway, I don't need the connection as a global variable. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could I improve the speed of my program then I am declaring the cursor like you did with the connection? So it doesn't creates a new one for each query, right?

Comment: Creating a cursor takes essentially no time at all.  There is almost no point in reusing them.  Creating a connection is quite expensive, so it is sensible to cache them.

Answer (score 0):

This too does work and you are guaranteed to always have one instance of the database

```
def singleton(class_):
    instances = {}

    def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in instances:
            instances[class_] = class_(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[class_]
    return get_instance

@singleton
class SingletonDatabase:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print('Initializing singleton database connection... ', random.randint(1, 100))
```

Answer (score -1):

The Reason you have to do all this is if you just create
a connection once and leave it at that you then
will end up trying to use a connection which is dropped

so you create a connection and attach it to your app
then whenever you get a new request check if the connection
still exists, with before request hook if not then recreate the
connection and proceeed.

```
on create_app
```

```py
    def create_app(self):

        if not app.config.get('connection_created'):
            app.database_connection = Database()
            app.config['connection_created'] = True
```

```
on run app
```

```py
    @app.before_request
    def check_database_connection(self):
        if not app.config.get('connection_created') or not app.database_connection:
            app.database_connection = Database()
            app.config['connection_created'] = True
```

this will insure that your application always runs with an active connection
and that it gets created only once per app

if connection is dropped on any subsequent call then it gets recreated again...

Comment: Understandable, but where do you get the `app` variable from, since my project does not have such a variable? I guess you are using a module like Flask or so, but since my project doesn't it wouldn't be possible to implement your solution. Am I right?