# How to create a reusable postgresql connection in a multithreaded python application

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm working on a multithreaded project that makes many database queries but the method now is creating a new database connection in thread every time before executing the queries and closing it after. As this is heavy operation I need a way to create a connection once and reuse it multiple times through the app. I've read about the threaded connection pool class of psycopg2, but I need help implementing it.

Consider this code, got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145633/how-to-initialize-a-database-connection-only-once-and-reuse-it-in-run-time-in-py):

```
class Database(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwagrs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            print("none")
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
            cls._instance.initialize_pool(*args, **kwagrs)
        return cls._instance

    def initialize_pool(self, *args, **kwagrs):
        self.db_pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(maxconn=5, minconn=1, *args, **kwagrs)

    def get_connection(self):
        try:
            return self.db_pool.getconn()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def return_connection(self, conn):
        self.db_pool.putconn(conn)

    def insert_query(self, query):
        connection = self.get_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.return_connection(connection)

    def update_query(self, query):
        connection = self.get_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.return_connection(connection)
```

The methods are then used by another class like so:

```
from .db import Database
import threading


class MainApp:
    self.records = [list of records ids]
    self.conn_str = "postgresql_connection_string"
    self.db = Database(self.conn_str)

    def insert_into_db(self, query):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.db.insert_query, args=query)
        thread.start()

    def update_records(self, query):
        for record in self.records:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.db.update_query, args=query)
            thread.start()

app = MainApp()
query = "INSERT ..."
app.insert_into_db(query)
update_query = "UPDATE ..."
app.update_records(update_query)
```

My main problem is that in `update_query` I receive `pool exhausted` error and therefore not updating anything. How do I solve it?

Comment: I don't use `threading`, but some searching indicates you need to `start()` a thread per [Thread](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html) and [Intro to Threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for pointing that out, added to the code the actual start of threads.